# Wordpress: How to load javascript in plugin when only the hostname exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a series of plugins that only load their respective javascript files, based on a page name, as follows:

```
function getnames_scripts() {
  global $post;
  if ( in_array( $post->post_name, array( 'somepage', 'anotherpage') ) ){
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'getnames-script',
      plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/getnames.js",
      array('jquery'),
      '1.0',
      true
    );
  }
}
```

How can I check to load the javascript when only the hostname is present, i.e. `192.0.0.50`, instead of `192.0.0.50/somepage/`?

Comment: A } is only missing from what I've posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='192.0.0.50'){
    // wow man
}else{
    // Oh man
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Really i am so much happy when i helped of someone. Welcome anytime :)